# login form with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried to use ajax to show error message if username or password are incorrect, and to go to tabeeb.html or secc.php if they are correct. but instead of going to the correct page, the page is presented in the dialog, like this[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXDdz.jpg). what is the wrong?

this is the form

```
 <form method="post"   class="bounceInDown animated">
 <input type="text" name="u" id="u" placeholder="User Name" class="bbb"><br>
 <input type="password" name="p" id="p" placeholder="Password" class="bbb">     
 <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()"  name="loginbtn" class=" btn 
 btn-primary " value="Log in"> 
 </form>
```

this is myfunction() function

```
function myFunction(){

var u = document.getElementById("u").value;
var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
var dataString = 'u1=' + u + '&p1=' + p ;

 if (u == '' || p == '') {
alert("Please Fill All Fieldsssssss");} 


else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxjss.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {

alert(html);
}
});
}
return false;
```

and this is ajaxjss.php

```
<?php
// Fetching Values From URL
$u2 = $_POST['u1'];
$p2 = $_POST['p1'];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password"); 
//   Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("project", $connection); // Selecting Database

if (isset($_POST['u1'])) {


// من تحت هو التجربة
$result = mysql_query("select * from test where student_name = '$u2' ") or 
 die("faild");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


if($row['student_name'] == $u2 && $row['student_password']==$p2)
{ $NoOFLetter = strlen($u2);

$result = substr($u2, $NoOFLetter-3,  $NoOFLetter);
if($result == "doc"){header('Location: tabeeb.html'); exit; }
if($result == "sec"){header('Location: secc.php'); exit;}

 exit; }

else{ 
$error_message = "Error in username or password!";}

// كل اللى فوق هو التجربة

if(!$query){

echo "error";

}else{echo "Form Submitted succesfully";}}
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

Comment: اسمعني .. هل تستخدم apache ?

Comment: a) **don't** use the deprecated `mysql` functions, which are also removed in PHP7. use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. b) your code is wide open to **SQL Injection** - imagine someone posting a username like `'; DROP TABLE test; -- ` c) is that your real password in your mysql_connect-function? if yes: **change it immediatelly**. (also: you should never use the root account for anything but administrative tasks) d) **never ever ever ever** store plain text passwords! use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment:  sql injection... security venerability

Comment: Yeah, that looked to be a real SQL password... I've submitted an edit taking it out, but you should really have it in a different file and just include it in your PHP code. Also, you've used the `$result` variable two different times, for completely different things, which is extremely confusing.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma it's been online once, though. meaning it's compromised anyway. it will *very likely* appear in several password dictionaries very soon.

Comment: @Franze Gleichmann Yeah, but at least other people that just look at this question won't get to see it. OP **needs** to change it though.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI   صحيح

Comment: يعطيك الصحة و العافية. أحسنت . فانتبه إذا

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  I know it is not secure. I am completely new with php and ajax. I just try to write this code and I can not find out why it does not run correctly !?

Answer (score 0):

Now check it

```js
function myFunction(){

var u = document.getElementById("u").value;
var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
var dataString = 'u1=' + u + '&p1=' + p ;

 if (u == '' || p == '') {
alert("Please Fill All Fieldsssssss");} 


else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxjss.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
  if(html=="error"){
    alert(html);
  }
  else{
    window.location.href="secc.php";
  }

}
});
}
return false;
```